# 1D Numpy array does not get reshaped into a 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
columns = np.shape(lines)[0]  # Gets x-axis dimension of array lines (to get numbers of columns)
lengths = np.zeros(shape=(2,1))  # Create a 2D array
# lengths = [[ 0.]
#            [ 0.]]
lengths = np.arange(columns).reshape((columns))  # Makes array have the same number of columns as columns and fills it with elements going up from zero <--- This line seems to be turning it into a 1D array
```

Output after printing lengths array:

```
print(lengths)
[0 1 2]
```

Expected Output Example:

```
print(lengths)
[[0 1 2]]  # Notice the double square bracket
```

This results in me not being able to enter data into a 2D parts of an array, because it now no longer exists:

```
np.append(lengths, 65, axis=1)
AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1
```

I want the array to be 2D so I can store "IDs" on the first row and values on the second (at a later point in the program). I'm also aware that I could add another row to the array instead of doing it at initialization. But I'd rather not do that since I heard that's inefficient and this program's success is highly dependent on performance.

Thank you.

Comment: You need `np.arange(columns).reshape(-1, columns)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you eventually want a 2d array with ids in one row and values in the second, I'd suggest starting with the right size

```
In [535]: arr = np.zeros((2,10),int)
In [536]: arr
Out[536]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
In [537]: arr[0,:]=np.arange(10)
In [538]: arr
Out[538]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Sure you could start with a 1 row array of ids, but adding that 2nd row at a later time requires making a new array anyways.  `np.append` is just a variation on `np.concatenate`.

But to make a 2d array from `arange` I like:

```
In [539]: np.arange(10)[None,:]
Out[539]: array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

`reshape` also works, but has to be given the correct shape, e.g. `(1,10)`.

In:

```
lengths = np.zeros(shape=(2,1))  # Create a 2D array
lengths = np.arange(columns).reshape((columns))
```

the 2nd `lengths` assignment replaces the first. You have to do an indexed assignment as I did with `arr[0,:]` to modify an existing array.  `lengths[0,:] = np.arange(10)` wouldn't work because `lengths` only has 1 column, not 10.  Assignments like this require correct pairing of dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't need 2D data to put into a column of a 2D array. You just need 1D data.
2. You can put the data into the 0th row instead of the 0th column if you change the organization of memory. This is copying data into contiguous memory (memory without gaps) and that is faster.

Program:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.arange(12)

#method 1
buf = np.zeros((12, 6))
buf[:,0] = data
print(buf)

#method 2
buf = np.zeros((6, 12))
buf[0] = data
print(buf)
```

Result:

```
[[  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  1.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  2.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  3.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  4.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  5.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  6.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  7.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  8.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  9.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [ 10.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [ 11.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]]
[[  0.   1.   2.   3.   4.   5.   6.   7.   8.   9.  10.  11.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]]
```